# ES6 class constructor shortcut for setting instance properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I seem to remember seeing a shortcut where you didn't have to do this.foo assignments in the constructor if the property and the constructor argument was named the same thing - but I can't seem to find the reference for it googling around.

For example:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Could you instead do something like

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height=height, width=width) { 
     // wasn't there a way to declare these arguments so it auto sets the instance variables?
  }
}
```

Comment: You're probably thinking of something like this in Typescript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

Comment: ah yes that was it - so it's a typescript only technique and not es6?

Comment: I don't remember anything like that being in ES itself.

Comment: ok - yeah then it's the typescript feature I'm thinking about.  Go ahead and create the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: https://dev.to/satansdeer/typescript-constructor-shorthand-3ibd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're into this kind of things, you could probably define a super-class that does this:

```
class BaseClass {
  constructor(names = [], values = []) {
    names.forEach((n, idx) => this[n] = values[idx]);
  }
}

class Polygon extends BaseClass {
  constructor(height, width) {
    super(['height', 'width'], arguments);
  }
}
```

Of course it's very debatable whether you should do this, but it's possible. Note that we could not rely on the names of the arg names in the constructor though because of possible minification problems.

Answer (score 20):

You could change it to:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    Object.assign(this, { height, width })
  }
}
```

This would mean you pass a singular object instead of multiple arguments

Answer (score 3):

**You are probably remembering ES6 object literal shorthand syntax:**

```
function makePolygon(height,width){
    return {height,width}; // in ES5 was return {height:height,width:width};
}

let poly = makePolygon(10,10);
console.log(poly); // {height: 10, width: 10}
```

**Another way to solve your problem is to use an ES6 class with a configuration object and default parameters:**

```
class Polygon{
    constructor(config={}){
        this.name = "Triangle";
        this.height = 10;
        this.width = 10;
        this.numSides = 3;
        Object.assign(this,config);
    }
}

let triangle = new Polygon();
let square = new Polygon({name: "Square", numSides: 4});
let pentagon = new Polygon({name: "Pentagon", numSides:5,height: 20,width: 20});

console.log(triangle,square,pentagon);
// Polygon {name: "Triangle", height: 10, width: 10, numSides: 3}
// Polygon {name: "Square", height: 10, width: 10, numSides: 4}
// Polygon {name: "Pentagon", height: 20, width: 20, numSides: 5}
```

Comment: That help's me alot i was looking for that, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

extend the prototype for more consice constructors

```
Object.prototype.initialize = function (obj) { Object.assign(this,obj) }

class Polygon {
  constructor(height,width) {
    this.initialize({height,width})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), just like in JavaScript, but with TypeScript you should specify that the constructor `values` is an `object`.

```
constructor(values: object) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
}
```

Here's a brief [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/zurfyx/pen/NXOoqj?editors=0010).

Answer (score 0):

How about using destruction:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor({height, width}) { Object.assign(this, arguments[0]); }
}
```

Though, creating this object will require creating a "config" object which, depending on your view, either adding clutter to the code or making it more readable:

```
console.log(new Polygon({height: 100, width: 200}));
```

will print:

```
Polygon {height: 100, width: 200}
```

One nice thing about this method is that if you receive polygon objects from the server as json, it is now trivially to revive them to their corresponding class:

```
let dataFromServer = "{\"polygons\":[{\"height\":10,\"width\":20},{\"height\":30,\"width\":40}]}";

console.log(JSON.parse(dataFromServer, (key, value) => {
  if (key === "polygons") return value.map(it => new Polygon(it));
  return value;
}));
```